# Cannot assign to 'accessoryType' in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6.1

When a cell is selected, I want it to be checked. I also want any other cell that is checked to have no accessory. Unfortunately, I get the error message which says I can't change the accessoryType. Is that because I am using the `visibleCells()` to get the cells? How to I overcome this error?

I have tried not using constants; I got the same error. I looked on the UITableView & UITableViewCell class reference, but I didn't see anything that could help me. My backup plan is to use a Picker View, but I'd prefer to use a Table View because of it's design.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cells = tableView.visibleCells()
    for oldCell in cells {
        if(oldCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark) {
            oldCell.accessoryType = .None //Cannot assign to 'accessoryType' in 'oldCell'
        }
    }
    cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    day = cell!.textLabel!.text!
    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/visibleCells), `visibleCells()` returns `[AnyObject]`. Due to Swifts type safety, it won't let you set `accessoryType` on `AnyObject` - it must be a `UITableViewCell`.

Try the following...

```
if let cells = tableView.visibleCells() as? [UITableViewCell] {
  for oldCell in cells {
    if oldCell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
      oldCell.accessoryType = .None
    }
  }
}
```